# NSMenuItem's title isn't updating through a bind

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

having some trouble getting a menu item's title to update through a binding. I'm not setting the title anywhere except through the binding, and the title is set correctly when the item is first added to the menu. However, it doesn't ever change if the value from its bound selector ever changes.

I also have the enabled attribute of the same menu item bound to the same selector, and it is updating itself just fine.

If I follow execution, it looks like the @"title" binding is only fired off once - when setting up the binding. However, the @"enabled" binding fires off every time the submenu displays.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
- (void)addToMenu:(MyObject *)myObject
{
    NSInteger insertIndex = [[myStatusItem menu] indexOfItemWithTitle:@"My Placeholder"] + 1;

    NSMenuItem *newMenuItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:[myObject name] action:nil keyEquivalent:@""];
    [newMenuItem setIndentation:1];

    NSMenu *newSubMenu = [[NSMenu alloc] init];

    NSMenuItem *newSubMenuItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] init];

    // This works great! Different return values from myBoolMethod affect the enabled attribute every time the menu is shown
    [newSubMenuItem bind:@"enabled" toObject:myObject withKeyPath:@"myBoolMethod" options:
        [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:myInverseBoolTransformer, NSValueTransformerBindingOption, nil]];

    // This sets the correct menu item title when FIRST drawn. However, every subsequent time the menu is shown, the title is still set to its init value
    [newSubMenuItem bind:@"title" toObject:myObject withKeyPath:@"myBoolMethod" options:
        [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:myTitleFromBoolTransformer, NSValueTransformerBindingOption, nil]];

    [newSubMenuItem setTarget:myObject];
    [newSubMenuItem setAction:@selector(doStuffThatChangesIndirectlyChangesBoolMethod)];

    [newSubMenu insertItem:newSubMenuItem atIndex:0];
    [newMenuItem setSubmenu:newSubMenu];

    [[myStatusItem menu] insertItem:newMenuItem atIndex:insertIndex];
}

@implementation myTitleFromBoolTransformer

+ (Class)transformedValueClass { return [NSString class]; }
+ (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation { return YES; }
- (id)transformedValue:(id)value {

    BOOL boolValue = [value boolValue];

    if(boolValue){
        return @"This is the DISabled value";
    } else {
        return @"This is the ENabled value";
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you returning nil from your `-transformedValue:` method? That code never executes

Comment: It was leftover from when I had an else/if. Doesn't need to be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could skip the binding all together and use [menu validation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSMenuValidation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) (set the title in the validate method).

A binding is more expensive.

Comment: Yeehaw, I like that a lot better. I wanted to keep that kind of stuff out of the model, so I created a new controller that uses the menuItem's representedObject.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer because I found out something that works, but I'm not going to accept it immediately because I still would like to hear from someone else.

I was binding directly to a method because I wanted to run some code to check a value that I can't get a notification for. I thought that by doing this it would execute that selector (i.e. the method) every time the KVO fired off a read. Well, I guess I don't really understand KVO because that wasn't what was happening with the title.

I ended up observing the `NSMenuDidBeginTrackingNotification` for my menu to fire off the code that checks my value, then sets a BOOL value in `myObject` along with `will/didChangeValueForKey`.

I'm still really confused as to why the `@"enabled"` binding worked without the `will/didChangeValueForKey` messages. EDIT: see [this apple discussion](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2007/Oct/msg00506.html) on why enabled worked. I REALLY need to re-read the KVC/KVO docs :(